# Making an enemy class for monogame c#

Tags: c#, monogame

I have been given the task to create an enemy class as well as an enemy manager. I am completely confused as to how I will attempt this. these classes will be added into one group project with my other group members. I need to include things such as enemy health, the sprite itself, animations etc. I am new to using Monogame and c# so it would be appreciated that any help given is in an extremely simple form.

Comment: Presumably you got as far as writing a class that has some variables to hold the health, sprite, etc? If so, can you show us what you have so far and explain what next step you want to take that you're stuck on? If you haven't gotten even that far yet, then it sounds like your understanding of your tools might be at too early a stage to make good use of this site just yet, and you should go work through some monogame tutorials to get up to speed on the basics.

Comment: If you want to use monogame did you consider using the free and open-source game engine Stride (fka Xenko)? It has a very similar API, but has a fully-featured editor. And the project is also just a visual studio solution...

Comment: Don't be afraid to ask this to your group members either. it's a project you're doing together.